# Cannot use nuget package System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler -

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package

This is easy to repro - VS2015, new project Universal Windows app.
Nuget console:

```
Install-Package System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler -Pre
```

I get an error then:

```
Install-Package : System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler 4.0.0-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler on 
UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
```

Looking inside the package, it appears this package references dotnet5.4.  With no entry for net46 etc.

I've read around a little and found (https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98) that dotnet5.4 replaces dnxcore50 (which is understood by VS2015).

How do I use this newer version of the library?  Is there someway to update DNX or something to make this work?

Thanks